# How to clear canvas html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to clear a Canvas.

I execute a setInterval function, who calls different "canvas" in any iteration.

After any execution, i call this function:

```
function deleteCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width,context.height);
    context.beginPath();
}
```

But no delete the canvas image.

Any idea?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this HTML5 Canvas Tutorial:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-clear-canvas/

You do not have to call `beginPath()`. Next to this, you should probably change `context` to `canvas`.

```
$("#clear").on('click', function () {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cwv0y6nh/

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `context.width` to `canvas.width`. The same for `height`.